# Location vector turning into degree vector

Tags: shader-nodes

I am making a node group that has an input coming from the location vector section of a mapping node shown below.

[image: mapping node]

However, the actual input for the node group shows up as degrees.

[image: node group inputs]

This causes my shader output to be messed up. I double-checked everything, and when I unplug the location from the input and just enter it manually in the node tree, it works perfectly fine and my shader shows up correctly. Is there something really obvious I'm missing, or is there a workaround?

Comment: What version of Blender are you using?  The current Dynamic Sky addon in 2.93 does not have a World Location option

Comment: I am making a custom Dynamic Sky node group that will better fit the work I do.

Comment: perhaps you could share a screenshot of that group?

Answer (score 0):

Welp, that's embarrassing. I just disconnected the node line for location and plugged it into a new input for the node group, and it fixed the problem.